# VBA: Deselecting filter automaticaly with a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find a macro that can deselect specific PivotItem from the table automaticaly.

```
Sub SetPivotTableFilter_AllNoEmpty()
Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvTbl_R12_3")

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvTb_3").CubeFields(24).EnableMultiplePageItems = True


With PT.PivotFields("[_Results].[Comments].[Comments]")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotItems("[_Results].[Comments].&[]").Visible = False
End With
End Sub
```

There is always an error comming saying "Application-defined or object-defined error.

I also have another code that is the opposite of the macro here

```
Sub SetPivotTableFilter_OnlyEmpty()
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvTbl_R12_2").PivotFields("[R01_Results].[Comments].[Comments]")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[R01_Results].[Comments].&[]")
End With

End Sub
```

This code is working i think the problem is when the code tries to run .PivotItem.
I also tried to find all of the items per iteration but it's also the same error in the PivotItem script. I would like to thank you in advance

Iteration solution:
Sub Iteration()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim filterField As PivotField
Dim filterItem As PivotItem

```
    ' Set the pivot table object (change "pvTbl_R12_3" to the actual name of your pivot table)
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvTbl_R12_3")
    
    ' Set the filter field (change "[R01_Results].[Comments].[Comments]" to the actual field name)
    Set filterField = pt.PivotFields("[R01_Results].[Comments].[Comments]")
    
    ' Clear any existing filters
    filterField.ClearAllFilters
    
    ' Find and deselect the empty values
    For Each filterItem In filterField.PivotItems
        If filterItem.Value = "" Then
            filterItem.Visible = False
        End If
    Next filterItem
End Sub
```

kind Regards